# How to phone number masking when call using twilio via PHP android?

Tags: php, twilio, android-studio-2.0

I want to create a calling between driver and rider using anonymous phone no. both are not see own no. it actually see the Twilio assign no. how can i integrate in custom PHP and please also tell me the work flow. if u have code must share your git link.
I will try using twilio sdk but still not working.i am not getting what we do from PHP side.

Comment: Read this: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223179848-Using-a-non-Twilio-number-as-the-caller-ID-for-outgoing-calls

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'd first start by working through this tutorial we have on [masked phone numbers with PHP](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/masked-numbers/php/laravel). This doesn't give you the Android app side of things, but will teach you about how number masking works.

Then, check out the documentation for [Twilio Programmable Voice for Android](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-sdk/android) and try to build the [quickstart application](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android).

Once you have those two parts, you should be able to fit them together to complete your solution. If you have any trouble with those bits, then please do post on StackOverflow with your code and the feature you are having difficulty with.